# Java Script Cache and PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I created a very basic MVC php application. The problem that I for see in the future is that I am echo-ing java script aswell in the footer.

So Question 1 - this does not get cached right ?

So I adopted the solution to rather write a single java script, which then contains functions. These functions then take in parameters from PHP and then I just echo these functions. Example:

Before:
In my footer.php

```
<?php 
$phpVariableSelector = "#toTop";
echo '$(document).scroll(function(){
        var e=$(document).scrollTop();
        //console.log("r",e);
        if(e>=200)
        {
            $("'.$phpVariableSelector.'").addClass("in");
        }
        else
        {
            $("'.$phpVariableSelector.'").removeClass("in");
        }
    });

$("'.$phpVariableSelector.'").click( function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(), $("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop: $("body").offset().top
  }, 500)
});'
?>
```

After:

In, app.js

```
<script>
function ScrollToTop($linkSelector)
{
    $(document).scroll(function()
    {
        var e=$(document).scrollTop();        
        if(e>=200)//If scrolled 200       
            $($linkSelector).addClass("in");        
        else        
            $($linkSelector).removeClass("in");        
    });

    $($linkSelector).click( function(e) {
      e.preventDefault(), $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: $("body").offset().top
      }, 500);
    });
}
</script>
```

And then in my footer.php file:

```
<script src="app.js"></script>
<?php
    echo 'ScrollToTop("#toTop")';
?>
```

Question 2 - Is this the right method to use or is there a solution more elegant out there ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the first question: you are right it is not cached

for the second question, this is how you should right it:

```
<script src="app.js"></script>
<script>
    <?php
        echo 'ScrollToTop("#toTop")';
    ?> 
</script>
```

however it looks like you will always echo out the same selector `#toTop`, if this is the case, then just do it in javascript since it'll never change, unless the selector will differ from page to page

Comment: Yes, I wanted to write it like that... Just forgot it seems. This is just a basic example to illustrate my point. The selector will/can change from page to page. Okay thanks I'm just gonna wait a day or 2 before accepting your answer to see what others say.

Comment: Since the selector is going to vary then this is the right way to write it, not because of the cache only but also not to repeat yourself and write same redundant code in every page, as well as whenever you need to change something in your code you will change it in one place instead of all pages.